# Pytorch RuntimeError: "host_softmax" not implemented for 'torch.cuda.LongTensor'

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am using pytorch for training models. But I got an runtime error when it was computing the cross-entropy loss.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deparser.py", line 402, in <module>
    d.train()
  File "deparser.py", line 331, in train
    total, correct, avgloss = self.train_util()
  File "deparser.py", line 362, in train_util
    loss = self.step(X_train, Y_train, correct, total)
  File "deparser.py", line 214, in step
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.long(), y)
  File "/home/summer2018/TF/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/summer2018/TF/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 862, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/summer2018/TF/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1550, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "/home/summer2018/TF/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 975, in log_softmax
    return input.log_softmax(dim)
RuntimeError: "host_softmax" not implemented for 'torch.cuda.LongTensor'
```

I think this is because the `.cuda()` function or conversion between `torch.Float` and `torch.Long`. But I have tried many ways to change the variable by `.cpu()`/`.cuda()` and `.long()`/`.float()`, but it still not work. This error message can't be found when searching it on google. Can anyone helps me? Thanks!!!

This is the code cause error:

```
def step(self, x, y, correct, total):
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = self.forward(*x)
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.long(), y)
    loss.backward()
    self.optimizer.step()
    _, predicted = torch.max(out.data, 1)
    total += y.size(0)
    correct += int((predicted == y).sum().data)
    return loss.data
```

And this function step() is called by:

```
def train_util(self):
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    avgloss = 0
    for i in range(self.step_num_per_epoch):
        X_train, Y_train = self.trainloader()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.cuda()
            for i in range(len(X_train)):
                X_train[i] = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X_train[i]))
                X_train[i].requires_grad = False
                X_train[i] = X_train[i].cuda()
            Y_train = torch.from_numpy(Y_train)
            Y_train.requires_grad = False
            Y_train = Y_train.cuda()
        loss = self.step(X_train, Y_train, correct, total)
        avgloss+=float(loss)*Y_train.size(0)
        self.optimizer.step()
        if i%100==99:
            print('STEP %d, Loss: %.4f, Acc: %.4f'%(i+1,loss,correct/total))

    return total, correct, avgloss/self.data_len
```

The input data `X_train, Y_train = self.trainloader()` are numpy arrays at begining.

This is a data sample:

```
>>> X_train, Y_train = d.trainloader()
>>> X_train[0].dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> X_train[1].dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> X_train[2].dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> Y_train.dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> X_train[0]
array([[   0,    6,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0, 1944, 8168, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,  815,  317, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       ...,
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,   23,    6, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,  297, ...,    0,    0,    0]])
>>> X_train[1]
array([ 6,  7,  8, 21,  2, 34,  3,  4, 19, 14, 15,  2, 13,  3, 11, 22,  4,
   13, 34, 10, 13,  3, 48, 18, 16, 19, 16, 17, 48,  3,  3, 13])
>>> X_train[2]
array([ 4,  5,  8, 36,  2, 33,  5,  3, 17, 16, 11,  0,  9,  3, 10, 20,  1,
   14, 33, 25, 19,  1, 46, 17, 14, 24, 15, 15, 51,  2,  1, 14])
>>> Y_train
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Try all possible combinations:

case 1:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out, y)`
I get:
`RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'target'`

case 2:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.long(), y)`
as description above

case 3:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.float(), y)`
I get:
`RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'target'`

case 4:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out, y.long())`
I get:
`RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at /pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:15`

case 5:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.long(), y.long())`
I get:
`RuntimeError: "host_softmax" not implemented for 'torch.cuda.LongTensor'`

case 6:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.float(), y.long())`
I get:
`RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at /pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:15`

case 7:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out, y.float())`
I get:
`RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'target'`

case 8:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.long(), y.float())`
I get:
`RuntimeError: "host_softmax" not implemented for 'torch.cuda.LongTensor'`

case 9:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.float(), y.float())`
I get:
`RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'target'`

Comment: So, you are computing the CrossEntropyLoss with a Long Tensor. Can you share a specific data sample that causes this? And *how* have you tried converting it to float? What format is `y`?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the comment! I add the data format in the description above. And the comments below are how I tried to convert it to float:

Comment: case 1:    
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out, y)`
I get:    
`RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'target'`

Comment: case 2:    
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.long(), y)`
as description above

Comment: case 3:    
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(out.float(), y)`   
I get:      
`RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.cuda.FloatTensor for argument #2 'target'`

Comment: You do realize that the error is about the *second* argument? Have you tried casting `y` as well?

Comment: @dennlinger Sorry for response lately. I have tried nine possible combinations of the arguments, but it still not works. I put all the results in the description above. Can you help me figure out where the mistake is?

Comment: Oh! I know where the problem is. `y` should be in torch.int64 dtype without one-hot encoding. And CrossEntropyLoss() will auto encoding it with one-hot (while `out` is the probability distribution of prediction like one-hot format). It can run now! Thank you for you help!

Comment: For best practices, consider adding this as a separated answer and accepting it as an answer. This makes it easier for others to later see the essence of your problem quicker :) Glad you could figure it out yourself!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know where the problem is.

`y` should be in `torch.int64` dtype without one-hot encoding.
And `CrossEntropyLoss()` will auto encoding it with one-hot (while out is the probability distribution of prediction like one-hot format).

It can run now!

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit more:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206550/pytorch-error-multi-target-not-supported-in-crossentropyloss/49209628

Input: (N,C) where C = number of classes
Target: (N) where each value is 0≤targets[i]≤C−1

Answer (score 5):

All right, this worked for me whenever I got error on similar lines (I am gonna keep it here for reference):

1. When calling your model on input ensure that your x is float.
2. However keep your target as long.
3. Call loss on model output and y without any typecasting.

```py
from torch import nn
net = nn.Linear(input, out_classes)
loss_criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

net = net.to(device)
X = X.to(device).float()
y = y.to(device).long()

y_hat = net(X)
l = loss_criterion(y_hat, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because I had flipped `targets` and `logits` and since logits are obviously not `torch.int64` it raised the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have met this problem.

RuntimeError: "host_softmax" not implemented for 'Long'

My fault is when use  nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), the order of loss_criterion(y_hat, y_label) parameters is wrong.