# RuntimeError: _thnn_mse_loss_forward is not implemented for type torch.cuda.LongTensor

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I'm using PyTorch,but I get a error!
My error code as following:

```py
for train_data in trainloader:
    example_count += 1
    if example_count == 100:
        break
    optimer.zero_grad()
    image, label = train_data
    image = image.cuda()
    label = label.cuda()
    out = model(image)
    _, out = torch.max(out, 1)
    # print(out.cpu().data.numpy())
    # print(label.cpu().data.numpy())
    # out = torch.zeros(4, 10).scatter_(1, out.cpu(), 1).cuda()
    # label= torch.zeros(4, 10).scatter_(1, label.cpu(), 1).cuda()
    l = loss(out, label)
    l.bakeward()
    optimer.setp()
    j += 1
    count += label.size(0)
    acc += (out == label).sum().item()
    if j % 1000 == 0:
        print(j + ' step:curent accurity is %f' % (acc / count))
```

the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VGG实现.py", line 178, in <module>
    utils.train(testloader,model)
  File "VGG实现.py", line 153, in train
    l=loss(out,label)
  File "/home/tang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 435, in forward
    return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/tang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2156, in mse_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))
RuntimeError: _thnn_mse_loss_forward is not implemented for type torch.cuda.LongTensor
```

I get a answer whose here 
[Pytorch RuntimeError: "host_softmax" not implemented for 'torch.cuda.LongTensor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818225/pytorch-runtimeerror-host-softmax-not-implemented-for-torch-cuda-longtensor)

But I don't know how to solve this question.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation of [`torch.max()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torch.html#torch.max):

> ```
> torch.max(input, dim, keepdim=False, out=None) -> (Tensor, LongTensor)
> ```
>
> Returns the maximum value of each row of the input tensor in the given
>   dimension dim. The second return value is the index location of each
>   maximum value found (argmax).

Your line of code

```
_, out = torch.max(out, 1)
```

Takes the *float* prediction of the model, `out`, and uses `torch.max()` to return the *argmax* = type *long* int index of the maximal prediction.
The error message you get is that your `loss` function (you are using cross entropy with softmax I guess) does not support a *long* type first argument.
Moreover, you cannot take derivative through argmax - so I don't think converting `out` to float using [`.to(torch.float)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to) is going to do you any good either.
The softmax function inside the loss function you are using is taking care of the argmax for you.

Comment: error is "l = loss(out, label)",I am using MSE loss

Comment: @linjietang indeed, this lines gives you the error, but the root cause for the error is the argmax you are taking from the prediction `out`. You need to pass the model output **directly** to the loss function **without** taking the `max`! Simply remove this line `_, out = torch.max(out, 1)` and you'll see your code working.

Comment: I solve this question.thanks,loss need one-hot,but my out's dtype is int64,out and label need change to one-hot